# Python reference to an new instance alternating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been playing with Python these days, and I realize some interesting way how Python assign id(address) to new instance (int and list).

For example, if I keep call id function with a number (or two different number), it return the same result. e.g.

```
>>> id(12345)
4298287048
>>> id(12345)
4298287048
>>> id(12345)
4298287048
>>> id(12342) #different number here, yet still same id
4298287048
```

Also when I declare the variable first and then call id() with it, the results are alternating like this.

```
>>> x = []; id(x)
4301901696
>>> x = []; id(x)
4301729448
>>> x = []; id(x)
4301901696
>>> x = []; id(x)
4301729448
```

Can someone please explain the Python work behind this? Also, is there a book or a site where I can read about this part of Python (assigning memory address, behind scene work, etc) since there is little I can find from [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)

Comment: Is it important that in one example you use large integers and in another you use lists?

Comment: No particular reason. I just happened to use int and list. I know Python saves canonical instances for numbers in a certain range, something like -5 to 255. So I used larger numbers to test. But since everything in python is first class object, I assume it's the same behavior for other objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating a new object **without any other references** and Python re-uses the memory location when the object is destroyed again after `id()` is done with it. In CPython, the result of `id()` *happens* to be the memory location of the object. From the [`id()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> **CPython implementation detail**: This is the address of the object in memory.

The line `id(12345)` creates a new `int()` instance; because it is bound as an argument to `id()` it has 1 reference to it. `id()` determines the memory location, and returns that result. In returning, the arguments are cleaned up and the reference count to the `int()` instance drops to 0, and Python cleans it up. The memory is freed.

The next line creates a new `int()` instance. There is memory available at the same location, so it is reused.

When, instead, you first bind the new object no a name, you created an extra reference to the object and it is not cleared up. The memory is not freed, and a new object will have to use a new memory address.

This part too is documented, again from the `id()` documentation:

> This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant **for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.**

Emphasis mine.

When rebinding (`x = []` when `x` is already set) Python **first** creates a new object, **then** rebinds `x` to point to that new object. This unbinds the old list *after* the new list is created. This means the old memory location is still occupied when the new list object is created.

To map that out to specific steps:

1. You create an object with `id() == 4301901696`.
2. `4301901696` is bound to `x` -> Reference count for `4301901696` is 1.
3. You create an object with `id() == 4301729448`.
4. `4301901696` is unbound from `x`. Reference count for `4301901696` drops to 0 and is cleared from memory.
5. `4301729448` is bound to `x`. Reference count for `4301729448` is 1.
6. You create a new object, `4301901696` is empty so the new object gets `id() == 4301901696`.
7. `4301729448` is unbound from `x`. Reference count for `4301729448` drops to 0 and is cleared from memory.
8. `4301901696` is bound to `x`. Reference count for `4301901696` is 1.
9. etc.

This too is part of the documentation, the [assignment statement documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) tells you what order assignment takes place in:

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list *[...]* and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

where *expression list* is everything on the right-hand-side of the `=` symbol.

Comment: Are there any implementations of python that use some other implementation of `id` besides memory location?  It seems there are many ways to uniquely identify an object ...

Comment: @wim: IronPython uses an [IdDispenser class](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/7be8b73e246bfb029880a7ebd8885cc541b705ac/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Runtime/IdDispenser.cs) to generate (sequential) IDs. Jython [does too](http://hg.python.org/jython/file/9cd9ab75eade/src/org/python/core/IdImpl.java) (not surprising since they have the same original author).