# hex(id()) returns alternating numbers for the same object, but id() returns a fixed number

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-memory-allocation

**Python version:** 3.6.9

I have discovered strange thing:

- `hex(id(A.__dict__))` returns alternating numbers on multiple calls
- `id(A.__dict__)` returns a fixed number every time.

**Demonstration**

```
class A:
    pass

print("{:#^30s}".format("hex"))
print(hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print()

print("{:#^30s}".format("decimal"))
print(id(A.__dict__))
print(id(A.__dict__))
print(id(A.__dict__))
print(id(A.__dict__))
print()

print("{:#^30s}".format("both"))
print(id(A.__dict__), hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(id(A.__dict__), hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(id(A.__dict__), hex(id(A.__dict__)))
print(id(A.__dict__), hex(id(A.__dict__)))
```

**Output**

```
#############hex##############
0x7f4c06312558   <--- one
0x7f4c06312cd8   <--- two
0x7f4c06312558   <--- one
0x7f4c06312cd8   <--- two

###########decimal############
139964498126168   <--- all the same
139964498126168
139964498126168
139964498126168

#############both#############
139964498126168 0x7f4c06312558   <--- all the same
139964498126168 0x7f4c06312558
139964498126168 0x7f4c06312558
139964498126168 0x7f4c06312558
```

From my knowledge, the `A` is a type object and it is created at once at the source compiling stage. It has some attributes, the `__dict__` is one of them and it should be the same object (`mappingproxy`) while whole lifetime of the `A` object. So its `id` should be fixed too and `hex(id(A.__dict__))` should return the same number every time. But I see other behavior in the `hex()` case. And that is more strange, this behavior disappears when `id()` is nearby.

What happens here?

Similar question: [Python reference to an new instance alternating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24086367/2913477)

Comment: FYI, I get alternating IDs with `id(...)` as well in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying `dict` for a type's `__dict__` isn't changing, but `__dict__` itself [is implemented much like a C-level `@property`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L835), where the implementing function [produces a *new* `mappingproxy` every time you access it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L760) (calling `PyDictProxy_New(type->tp_dict);`, where `tp_dict` is the actual underlying `dict` pointer).

So much like [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24086367/2913477), the issue here is an object being repeatedly created, with the precise allocation pattern of `id()` and `hex` changing the allocation interleaving in the allocator so you don't always get back the same memory.

This might seem inefficient, but it doesn't matter much in practice. Most use of the class uses `tp_dict` implicitly and directly, so no mapping proxy is created. It's fairly rare to actually access `__dict__` explicitly at the Python layer, so the overhead of rewrapping is rarely paid at all.